# Concatenate and add a character to integer columns in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a 10 Character length values in a column in SQL Server. I need to split that column at fixed length and remove the leading zeros and add a - after each of the values.
I am able to split the values by using Substring and converting them to int. It is working well.

However, when I try to concatenate it is failing. Appreciate if you can help.

```
SELECT TOP 1 R.COL1, CAST(SUBSTRING(R.COL1,1,1) AS int) AS F1,CAST(SUBSTRING(R.COL1,2,5) AS int) AS F2,CAST(SUBSTRING(R.COL1,7,4) AS int) AS F3 CAST(SUBSTRING(R.COL1,1,1) AS int) +'-' +CAST(SUBSTRING(R.COL1,2,5) AS int)  +'-' + CAST(SUBSTRING(R.COL1,7,4) AS int) AS finalString  FROM MYTABLE R
```

If the value for COL1 IS 1012950001 the finalString I am expecting is 1-1295-1
however the result I am getting from the above query is 1297 as it is adding all the values.
Appreciate if you can help.

Comment: Don't cast them to int if you don't want `+` to treat them as ints

Comment: Converting, however, is the easiest way to remove the leading zeroes though, @DaveCosta . The alternative would be using `PATINDEX` and `STUFF`.

Comment: Welcome to [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: @Larnu doesn't SQL Server have `TRIM()`?

Comment: Yes, however, how does that help remove leading zeroes, @DaveCosta ?

Comment: @Larnu "The TRIM() function removes the space character OR other specified characters from the start or end of a string."  -- other specified characters

Comment: Which would turn `'060'` to `'6'` or `'1230'` to `'123'`, @DaveCosta . That isn't desired. `TRIM` removes the specific characters from **both** sides, the OP wants only the leading characters to be removed. `LTRIM`, however, doesn't support having the characters to be removed being supplied.

Comment: Ah true.  I was thinking of LTRIM but didn't realize that limitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `+` operator with a numerical data type and a `varchar` that cannot *implicitly* be converted to that data type. Something like `1 + 'a'` isn't going to work, as `'a'` isn't an `int`, and can't be implicitly converted to one.

If you are mixing data types, then use `CONCAT`, which implicitly converts each part into a `(n)varchar`:

```
CONCAT({Numerical Expression},'a',{Other varchar Expression})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` method to concatenate the substring value

```
select 
concat(CAST(SUBSTRING('1012950001',1,1) AS int), '-', 
CAST(SUBSTRING('1012950001',2,5) AS int), '-', 
CAST(SUBSTRING('1012950001',7,4) AS int)) AS finalString
```

This will give you the expected result `'1-1295-1'`